# Can I close/terminate an running thread from its thread function?

Tags: c

I have created a thread, with a custom thread function. I have a condition in the thread function that if it becomes true, I want to close the thread from inside the thread function.

Is it possible?

Comment: Just return from the function?

Comment: Yes, add `return` statement to the thread function, if condition is true.

Comment: so if i add return it should close the tread ??

Comment: I Think i get u gays , the fact that the thread func is returned it closes the thread ...

Comment: Use `pthread_exit()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can return from the thread and if you want to return some value, you can use [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using pthread for the thread functionlaity. You can call the [pthread_detach](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html)() function in your custom thread function after creating the thread. In the created thread just returning from the thread function will be sufficient to close the thread and release all the resources associated with the thread.

Answer (score 0):

For PThreads there are two ways to end a thread **cleanly**.

- Detached the thread using [`pthread_detach()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html). To end it then call [`pthread_exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html). To find a thread's phtread-id from inside the thread itself use [`phtread_self()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_self.html).
- Call [`pthread_exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html) and have another thread call `pthread_join()` on the pthread-id received when creating the thread that ended.

**If you miss to call [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) on a thread not having been detached by calling [`pthread_detach()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html), the resources in use by the thread will not be released, even after the thread ended.**

**This could lead to a shortage on memory and/or other system resources. Take care this does not happen.**

---

A third was to end a thread is to just cancel it using [`pthread_cancel()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cancel.html), which typically isn't initated by the thread itself (as I could just use one of the two ways described above to end itself), but from another thread in the situation where the thread to end is not aware of this and could not be notified to do so.

The need to cancel a thread should rarely arise, and if it does one might start to overthink the program's design.